# Найти все совершенные числа, меньшие n : JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for

Помогите. Вот сам код, который, к сожалению, не работает:Посмотрите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

```js
var result = 0;
for (var i = 6; i < 500; i++) {

  for (var j = 1; j < i; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) {
      result = result + j;

    };

  }
  if (result == i) {
    console.log(i);
  };
}
```

Comment: А какие есть ограничения на n? А то ведь можно банально сделать так: `const nums = [6, 28, 496, 8128, 33550336, 8589869056, 137438691328, 2305843008139952128, 2658455991569831744654692615953842176]; let i; for (i = 0; i<nums.length && nums[i]<n; i++); console.log(nums.slice(0, i).join());` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

result не сбрасывается для каждого числа, и поэтому хранит сумму множителей *всех* чисел от 6 до 500.

Помимо этого, множители, вообще, ищутся так: 1; 2, если число четное; далее все нечетные не превосходящие Math.sqrt(i) (можно более оптимизированно, это самый простой цикл).